# How to allow entry from a specific email domain in a Google pop-up in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

How can I use Google SignIn pop-up on my React.js web application only for a specific email domain?

I am trying to allow entry only to an email with the form : "@ac.sce.ac.il" from the code itself.

I tried the following code to allow the user to see only the email that matches my needs but it doesn't work:

```
const googleSignIn = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    provider.setCustomParameters({'hd': '@ac.sce.ac.il'});   <----- Not Working

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(function (result) {
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;
      console.log(user);
    });
  };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem, I had to remove the '@' character, and now it works as I wanted.

I changed the line that didn't work to this:

```
provider.setCustomParameters({'hd': 'ac.sce.ac.il'});
```